# Not able to inject RedisCache/SyncCache/StatefulRedisConnection beans in micronaut 4.2.1 version

Tags: redis, connection, micronaut, inject, lettuce

We are using Micronaut 2 with Redis and jdk11 in my aws lambda application. We have upgraded jdk17 with micronaut 4. As part of the upgrade, we are facing issue with Redis and getting io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException.

Detailed error message: Message: No bean of type [io.micronaut.configuration.lettuce.cache.RedisCache] exists. The bean [RedisCache] is disabled because it is within the package [io.micronaut.configuration.lettuce] which is disabled due to bean requirements:

- Required property [redis] with value [null] not present.

How to solve this.. Please suggest.

I want micronaut to automatically inject and initialize the redis bean. I have tried injecting RedisCache,SyncCahe,StatefulRedisConnection but these are not working. If you create custom redisclient without adding @inject , this is working. But I don't want to manage the custom redisclient creation myself.